# Retraining an existing machine learning model with new data

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, training-data, supervised-learning

I have a ML model which is trained on a million data set (supervised classification on text) , however I want the **same model** to get trained again as soon as a new data comes in (training data).

This process is continuous and I **don't** want to **loose** the power of the **model's prediction** every time it receives a new data set. I don't want to merge the new data with my history data (~1 million samples) to train again.

So the ideal would be for this model to grow up gradually training on all data over a period of time and preserving the intelligence of the model every time it receives a new training set data. What is the best way to **avoid retraining all historical data**? A Code sample would help me.

Answer (score 6):

You want to a look into [incremental learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_learning) techniques for that. Many [`scikit-learn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) estimators have an option to do a `partial_fit` of the data, which means that you can incrementally train on small batches of data.

A common approach for these cases is to use [`SGDClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) (or regressor), which is trained by taking a fraction of the samples to update the parameters of the model on each iteration, thus making it a natural candidate for online learning problems. However, you must retrain the model through the method `partial_fit`, otherwise it will train the whole model again.

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit)

> SGD allows minibatch (online/out-of-core) learning, see the partial_fit method

Though as mentioned there are several other estimators in `scikit-learn` that have the `partial-fit` API implemented, as you can see in the section [incremental learning](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning), including [`MultinomialNB`](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB), [`linear_model.Perceptron`](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html#sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron) and [`MiniBatchKMeans`](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans) among others.

---

Here's a toy example to illustrate how it's used:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

clf = SGDClassifier()

kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
kf_splits = kf.split(X)

train_index, test_index = next(kf_splits)
# partial-fit with training data. On the first call
# the classes must be provided
clf.partial_fit(X[train_index], y[train_index], classes=np.unique(y))

# re-training on new data
train_index, test_index = next(kf_splits)
clf.partial_fit(X[train_index], y[train_index])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is incremental learning, there is an excellent library called creme which helps you with that.

All the tools in the library can be updated with a single observation at a time, and can therefore be used to learn from streaming data.

Here are some benefits of using creme (and online machine learning in general):

Incremental: models can update themselves in real-time.
Adaptive: models can adapt to concept drift.
Production-ready: working with data streams makes it simple to replicate production scenarios during model development.
Efficient: models don't have to be retrained and require little compute power, which lowers their carbon footprint
Fast: when the goal is to learn and predict with a single instance at a time, then creme is a order of magnitude faster than PyTorch, Tensorflow, and scikit-learn.
 Features

Check out this: https://pypi.org/project/creme/